# How to load/populate an existing database record to a ReactJs form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got this form where you can update user data (code, article, price, vat, status, companyid).

I would like to populate the Update/Edit form with user data so i can easly modify them (once this form shows up, i would like to get data from API in each input and show them as input value).

```
import { getUsers, editUser } from '../Service/api'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

const DialogEditUser = (data) => {
  const [RowData, SetRowData] = useState([])
  const [ViewEdit, setEditShow] = useState(false)
  const [id, setId] = useState('')
  const [code, setCode] = useState('')
  const [article, setArticle] = useState('')
  const user = { id, code, article }

  const normalize = (v) => ({
    code: String(v.code),
    article: String(v.article),
  })

  const handleEditShow = () => {
    setEditShow(true)
  }
  const handleEditClose = () => {
    setEditShow(false)
  }

  const handleEdit = () => {
    editUser(data.props, normalize(user))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers()
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <CButton
        style={{
          marginRight: '10px',
          color: 'info',
          border: 'none',
          boxShadow: `2px 2px 9px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6)`,
        }}
        onClick={() => handleEditShow(SetRowData(data), setId(data.id))}
      >
        Edit
      </CButton>
      <CModal
        visible={ViewEdit}
        onClose={handleEditClose}
        backdrop={'static'}
        keyboard={false}
        portal={false}
      >
        <CModalHeader>
          <CModalTitle>Edit User:</CModalTitle>
        </CModalHeader>
        <CModalBody>
          <CForm>
            <CFormInput
              type="text"
              id="exampleFormControlInput1"
              label="Code :"
              placeholder="Enter Code"
              text=" "
              aria-describedby="exampleFormControlInputHelpInline"
              name="code"
              onChange={(e) => setCode(e.target.value)}
              defaultValue={RowData.code}
            />
            <CFormInput
              type="text"
              id="exampleFormControlInput2"
              label="Article :"
              placeholder="Enter Article"
              text=" "
              aria-describedby="exampleFormControlInputHelpInline"
              name="article"
              onChange={(e) => setArticle(e.target.value)}
              defaultValue={RowData.article}
            />
        <CModalFooter>
          <CButton color="secondary" onClick={() => setEditShow(false)}>
            Cancel
          </CButton>
          <CButton
            color="primary"
            onClick={() => {
              handleEdit()
              setEditShow(false)
            }}
          >
            Update
          </CButton>
        </CModalFooter>
      </CModal>
    </>
  )
}

export default DialogEditUser
```

src/Service/**api**.js:

```
//...
export const getUsers = async (id) => {
  id = id || ''
  try {
    return await axios.get(`${baseURL}`, config)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error while calling getUsers api ', error)
  }
}
//...
```

Comment: What isn't working in your code?

Comment: @David my code is working, no errors at all, i just want to populate data of user like his (code, article...etc) that we get them from api and then should put them as value in inputs.
so once the form show up, i want to get see user data in the inputs.
i hope you understand now.

Comment: I tried to use `RowData` as  `DefaultValue` but it didn't work. This is exactly my problem. But i'm open for any other suggestions too.

Comment: And what have you tried?  `getUsers()` returns a `Promise` which resolves to data.  Currently nothing is done with that returned value.  Have you tried awaiting that `Promise` and using the returned data in any way?

Comment: nope, i didn't..

Comment: you are just calling ```getUsers```, save the response in some variable then use that variable to set default value on your form. [check](https://www.codingdeft.com/posts/react-fetch-data-api/) this article, it has basic as well as advance example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `function` that handle loading of data then created a `useEffect` function and put inside the handled function so the data will be loaded in `inputs` (populated):

```
useEffect(() => {
    loadArticleDetails()
  }, [])

  const loadArticleDetails = async () => {
    const response = await getUsers(id)
    console.log('Loading article details ', response)
    setArticleData(response.data.find((x) => x.id == data.props))
  }
```

And in inputs, change each defaultValue to:

```
//...
defaultValue={articleData.code}  //Change code to its corresponding data: price, vat..etc
//...
```

Comment: Thank you, a very real close approach solution.