# How to populate data in ant design Form.List component (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want to prepopulate my `Form.List` fields from the data I'm getting from backend, but have tried various methods, `Form.getFieldsValue()` do show that data is there, but it is not being displayed in the fields.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73866787/load-populate-an-existing-database-record-to-a-react-js-form/73878142#73878142

Comment: no it doesn't, I'm not looking for `defaultValue` and looking for `value` as the same form fields will be populated again with different values, depending on what parent is selected.

Comment: how your form is rendered? can you please share some code?

Comment: i guess you can try value too with this code.

Comment: This depends how you set your data in Form.List. Please share you code.

Comment: Hey, I solved it, it was happening because inside my `<Form.Item>` I was having few `<div>` before input field. Removing those div's populated my Input fields, by simply using `setFormFields`.